# How can I apply a custom sort rule to a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, mvvm, wpftoolkit

When the user does a column sort in my `DataGrid`, I want all null or empty cells to be sorted to the bottom, rather than the top.

I wrote an `IComparer<T>` that makes sure blanks are always sorted downward, but I can't figure out how to apply it to the columns of my `DataGrid`. Note that the *initial* sort of the `DataGrid`, which I'm doing with the LINQ `OrderBy()` method, works great. The problem is that all subsequent sorts performed by the user sort the blanks to the top.

**Comparer Code**

```cs
public class BlankLastStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
            return 1;
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(y))
            return -1;
        else
            return string.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

**Questions**

How do I get the `DataGridColumn` to use my comparer? Or if this is not possible, can you offer a workaround? I'm hoping for an MVVM friendly solution if possible.

Comment: Could you this approach, quite flexible and easy to use.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866332/3601887

Answer (score 34, accepted):

this is how i do it : I do derive from the grid to keep all of this inside the class, so i attach to event handlers internally

attach to the sorting event

```cs
dataGrid.Sorting += new DataGridSortingEventHandler(SortHandler);
```

implement the method (i do this in a derived class)

```cs
void SortHandler(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridColumn column = e.Column;

    IComparer comparer = null;

    //i do some custom checking based on column to get the right comparer
    //i have different comparers for different columns. I also handle the sort direction
    //in my comparer

    // prevent the built-in sort from sorting
    e.Handled = true;

    ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

    //set the sort order on the column
    column.SortDirection = direction;

    //use a ListCollectionView to do the sort.
    ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);

    //this is my custom sorter it just derives from IComparer and has a few properties
    //you could just apply the comparer but i needed to do a few extra bits and pieces
    comparer = new ResultSort(direction);

    //apply the sort
    lcv.CustomSort = comparer;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that depending on the type of collection your DataGrid was bound to, you may have to cast the result of GetDefaultView to [A Different Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#how_to_create_a_view).

Answer (score 6):

I have an MVVM solution for this problem which makes use of attached behaviours. If you prefer to use code-behind, @Aran's solution will do the trick too.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218963/2115261