# When clicking on Datagrid ColumnHeader - How is sorting taking place? And how to override it?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, .net-4.0, datagrid

When clicking on a DataGrid ColumnHeader, the datagrid would automatically sort the data, if the underlying dataSource is a CollectionView.

How does it work internally, does it just add SortDescriptors() to the View in order to sort or does it utilize an IComparer class?

I think its rather using SortDescriptors, hence its so slow in sorting.

I have done some research and it says using

`CollectionView.CustomSort = a class implementing IComparer` is much faster approach.

So in order to try this approach, how do I override the automatic sorting mechanism of DataGrid - when clicked on a columnheader - and do my own sorting with the CustomSort?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Sorting Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.sorting.aspx) which will give you the Column they are using to sort and in which direction.