# How to Sort DataGridTemplateColumn (which uses MultiBinding), in the same order as the Multibound fields

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, multibinding, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a custom entity, which contains FirstName, LastName properties (it has other properties also). I bind this entity to a datagrid, which displays FullName (LastName, FirstName) as a DataGridTemplateColumn (using MultiBinding with StringFormat). Users are allowed to sort datagrid columns and when they click on FullName columns, records must be sorted by LastName and then FirstName (sort direction will toggle based on the number of clicks). I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the desired sorting (multi column) in the above scenario?

I tried using SortMemberPath attribute but there I can specify only one column.

I Know if I add a custom ReadOnly property named FullName to my entity things would work, but I just want to understand if it is possible to achieve the same with MultiBinding implemented.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: I would like to know the same thing. It must be a very common scenario to want to sort a template column on more than one field. The only idea I have is creating another property to hold the presorted rank of each entity relative to the others in the collection. This is costly though because you'd have to perform the sort before you even know if the user wants to sort by that column.

Answer (score 0):

I found another thread that helped out. You can use the DataGrid.Sorting event to override the default sorting as mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid). That answer says he or she overrides the DataGrid, but you don't have to. It also assumes you've used an IList as your data source so here is an example that, instead, assumes a DataTable/DataView (IBindingList) source:

```
    private void dgPeople_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Assumes you've named your column colFullName in XAML
        if (e.Column == colFullName)
        {
            ListSortDirection direction = (e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

            //set the sort order on the column
            e.Column.SortDirection = direction;

            //Prevent the default sorting
            e.Handled = true;

            //Get the static default view that the grid is bound to to redefine its sorting
            BindingListCollectionView cv = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgPeople.ItemsSource);
            cv.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            cv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FirstName", direction));
            cv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("LastName", direction));
            cv.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

I found out the hard way that you need to perform the sorting on the ICollectionView (the BindingListCollectionView in this example), and not the DataView. If you don't, the sorting you perform on the DataView would be overwritten by the sorting set on the ICollectionView.

I found this link very helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#what_are_collection_views

Comment: The only shortcoming I've run into with this solution is I'm not sure how to handle sorting by multiple columns at once (shift+click sorting)