# Wpf data grid custom column sorting

Tags: wpf, sorting

How do I add a special sorting method to a particular column to allow different types of sorting(such as sorting 120.5.1.50 in between 120.5.1.12 and 120.5.1.110 instead of having 120.5.1.110 be the lowest value.

Also how do I allow click header sorting of a custom type bound it a template column. Is this even possible?

Comment: This can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF DataGrid CustomSort for each Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122751/wpf-datagrid-customsort-for-each-column)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement IComparer and define your own comparing logic.

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<Object>
{

    public int Compare(Object stringA, Object stringB)
    {
         // Your logic here
    }
}
```

After you can just use LINQ OrderBy method with your custom comparer.

```
items = items.OrderBy(x => property, comparer).ToList();
```

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby).

**Edit**
TO override the default sorting behaviour of a WPF Datagrid, refer to the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid).

Comment: the question isn't about how to implement sorting but how to add sorting behaviour for wpd datagrid when you click on a column heading

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated my answer with a link. Look at the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the custom sort order after clicking the column header, you can use an attached behaviour. I came up with this solution which seems to work well:

[WPF DataGrid CustomSort for each Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122751/wpf-datagrid-customsort-for-each-column)

This is an MVVM solution - there are probably simpler ways of doing this if you want to delve into the world of code-behind.