# Sorting the radGridView by clicking on column header

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, telerik

I am working on a wpf application.It shows some result in a datagrid.

I want to sort a column in a data grid.column contains `double` values.RadDataGrid provides inbuilt sort mechanism when you click on the column header.

My problem is ..when data is not available I am putting NA as result. so my column values are like `345,567,NA,567,88 etc`

I am unable to sort the column...

For writing `NA` m converting double as string...so I think this is the problem.

What is the option so that when i get no data still i want to show such value that can be treated as double and my column will be sorted.

It is sorting on the first digit.
[image]

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid

Comment: My data is sorting on first digit.

Answer (score 0):

In your grid, set the 'SortExpression' property to a numeric version of the property.  Something like this...

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="MyPropertyAsString" HeaderText="MyValue" SortExpression="MyPropertyAsDouble" />
```