# SortMemeberPath from another table

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml

I want to create a `DataGrid` with `ItemsControl` of cars
the car class contains the following: CarLicense & DriverID(ForeignKey)
DriverID is connected to DriversTable  and this table has the following properties:
DriverID, DriverName

i want to sort the data grid by DriverName is it possible' without adding drivername to the car class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle the `Sorting` event of the `DataGrid` and implement your own custom sorting logic:

[How can I apply a custom sort rule to a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid)

Or you could create a view model class that contains the CarLicense , DriverId and DriverName properties and bind to a collection of such objects. Then the built-in sorting functionality will work.

Using auto-generated entity classes directly in a WPF or other client application is rarely very useful.