# Force date sorting in string properties in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid, that has all columns binded to string properties.

I create these columns in runtime, so I need to make the bind programmatically:

```
var c = new DataGridTextColumn();
c.Header = myProperty;
c.Binding = new Binding(myProperty);
if (thisColumnsIsDate())
    c.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
myGrid.Columns.Add(c);
```

The problem is that the grid sorts these date columns like `string`, not `DateTime`.

This is the grid definition:

```
<DataGrid
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="2"
            Name="myGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            IsEnabled="True"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRow}"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke"
            PreviewKeyDown="gridResult_OnKeyDown">
```

What´s missing?

Answer (score 0):

This should correct the sorting for Date columns:

```
c.SortMemberPath = myProperty;
```

But if your property is a string you need to convert it to a DateTime first:

```
var c = new DataGridTextColumn();
c.Header = myProperty;

if (thisColumnsIsDate())
{
    myDateTimeProperty = DateTime.Parse(myProperty);
    c.Binding = new Binding(myDateTimeProperty);
    c.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
    c.SortMemberPath = myDateTimeProperty;
}
else
{
    c.Binding = new Binding(myProperty);
    c.Binding.StringFormat = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}";
    c.SortMemberPath = myProperty;
}
myGrid.Columns.Add(c);
```

Moreover, you can implement your own comparer: [How can I apply a custom sort rule to a WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129601/366064)

Comment: It still sorting like a string, not a date value.

Comment: @Beetlejuice  is myProperty a string?

Comment: Yes, it is. In fact, all binded properties are strings.

Comment: @Beetlejuice so I guess changing some of them to DateTime is not an option. can you cast it to DateTime and add it as a new property?  this way you can bind with no problem.