# Update SortMemberPath on property change

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a property, `SortingName`, used as the `SortMemberPath` for one of my columns in my `DataGrid`. However, I would like this property to get updated every time the header is clicked (i.e. call its setter again).

Here is the property:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual string SortingName {
        get { return m_sortingName; }
        set
        {
            if (m_sortingName == null)
                m_sortingName = value;
            m_sortingName = m_sortingName.StartsWith("_") ? value : "_" + value;
        }
    }
```

And here is the XAML for the `DataGrid` it's used in (the first column is the :

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Templates" 
                              Width="200" SortMemberPath='SortingName'>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type request:ModelDocument}">
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left">
                  <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                      <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding PrettyName}"/>
                    </Style>
                  </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
              </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>

...remaining columns
```

I've tried to use a `Binding` for the `SortMemberPath`, and assigning an `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, but it did not seem to do anything. I had also attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129601/how-can-i-apply-a-custom-sort-rule-to-a-wpf-datagrid) method, but had issues with the how my `ItemsSource` is defined. So I would prefer to update the property on click instead.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I simply created a function in my custom class that extends off DataGrid, and added it to its `Sorting` event handler.

```
    public DataGridEx()
    {
       Sorting += UpdateSorting;
    }
```

The `UpdateSorting` function appends an ASCII character at the beginning of the string depending on what the order I'd like the item to stay in. In this example I want folder type items to stay at the top, so when the list is ascending I add a low alphabetical character (e.g. `!`), and vice versa for the descending list. This way the folders are always at the top.

This isn't the best solution in my opinion (and honestly not very related to the question itself) but it works for now. If anyone has a better answer please feel free to post!